# How do I find the account associated with Google API keys

Tags: api, google-maps-api-3, maps, key, account

I recently started a new job where there is nobody left who had worked on a google maps application.

I can see the API key that is being used, but they key doesn't show up underneath the only google account I know of for our team (other API keys show, but not the one we use for maps).

Is there a way to identify which account or email address is associated with a google API key?  I am trying to log in an manage the domains allowed with that key.

Any help tracking this down is appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just create new keys from the accounts you know about?

Comment: Maybe OP wants to have the usage history, etc. I doubt there is a way to find that out though.

Comment: There's no way to find that, due this information is protected by Google as described by @Stephen in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42076722/3033184