# Find owner of Maps API Key

Tags: google-maps

I have been working on a website that has implemented Google Maps API key, but I need to know who the owner is for the API key.  Is there any way to find out.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You mean this key does not belong to you, a coworker or your company/employer ?

Comment: Yes correct.  The key was hard coded into the project ".NET" by a previous developer and the client want's to know who generated the key. For some reason they want to use the same key on their new project.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The owner of a key is private information protected by Google. There is no way for end users to find the owner of a key. If you don't know the owner of a key and you need to make modification or add restrictions to the key, it may be best to create a new API key. You can do that by following the steps here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Once you have a new API key created you can use it in your project and manage it in the console. This way you will have more control over the key  and project and will be able to add restrictions or billing information if necessary.